# Click on button doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleText is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I've started learning JavaScript. I want to change text on the button after clicking on it, but I have a message that function 'toggleText' is not defined (the same 'demo').

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>String output</title>
    <script type="module" src="Game.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
import Game from "./Game.js";

const game = new Game(
  "play",
  [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
)

const toggleText = function (button_id,fieldIndex) 
{
     document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = "X";
     game.setX(fieldIndex);
};

const content = `
  <main>
  <button id="btn" onclick="demo()">Old Text</button>
    <button id="myButton" onClick="toggleText(this.id);">Lock</button>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <button class="button" id="b0" onclick=" toggleText(this.id,0);" type="button">${game.field[0]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button b1" onclick="toggleText(this.id,1)" type="button">${game.field[1]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button b2" onclick="toggleText(this.id,2)" type="button">${game.field[2]}</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,3)" type="button">${game.field[3]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,4)" type="button">${game.field[4]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,5)" type="button">${game.field[5]}</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,6)" type="button">${game.field[6]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,7)" type="button">${game.field[7]}</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button class="button" onclick="toggleText(this.id,8)" type="button">${game.field[8]}</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>  
`;

function demo(){
  const button = document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "New text";  };

document.body.innerHTML = content;
```

Game.js:

```
class Game {
constructor(
    status,
    field = []
){
    this.status = status;
    this.field = field;
    
}
setX(fieldIndex){
    field[fieldIndex] = "X";
    console.log(this.field);
}

reset(){

}
}

export default Game;
```

I tried different methods in function (innerHTML, innerText, etc.) but it doesn't work, because "not defined" error.
Also, I think is no need to have '${game.field[1]}' in code, but this is just a first version.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Creating buttons in a string literal is properly the first mistake to start with. Then a const to actually defining a functions with variable parameters instead of using a function in the first place...

Comment: I want to chenge text in button after clinking it... So, what should I change and how?

Comment: what are you ulimativly trying to do? Create a tic tac toe?

Comment: Yes - it's Tic Tac Toe (or Kółko i Krzyżyk in some country).

Comment: ok instead of using a table, read into CSS-Grid. Then read into event delegation and `addEventListener` instead of using the onclick-attribute. Consider `data`-attributes instead of id's

Answer (score 0):

For any reason I couldn't make it run as a module either, but it works when you put the *Game* class directly into your `script.js` and remove `type="module"` from your html file.

```js
class Game {
  constructor(status, field = []) {
    this.status = status;
    this.field = field;
  }
  setX(fieldIndex) {
    this.field[fieldIndex] = "X";
    console.log(this.field);
  }

  reset() {}
}

const game = new Game("play", [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]);

function toggleText(button_id, fieldIndex) {
  document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = "X";
  game.setX(fieldIndex);
}

function demo() {
  const button = (document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "New text");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>String output</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <button id="btn" onclick="demo()">Old Text</button>
      <button id="myButton" onclick="toggleText(this.id)">Lock</button>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b0"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,0)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button b1"
              id="b1"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,1)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button b2"
              id="b2"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,2)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b3"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,3)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b4"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,4)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b5"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,5)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b6"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,6)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b7"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,7)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="button"
              id="b8"
              onclick="toggleText(this.id,8)"
              type="button"
            ></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some more points:

- in the `setX` function was missing a *this*, which is needed for accessing variables in classes
- since you change the buttons' texts by `document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = "X";` anyway, you do not need to hold all the buttons as a string variable, but can just use html elements
- not that much relevant but you're mixing up camel case (*fieldIndex*) and kebab case (*button_id*) syntax. In JS it's common to use camel case only :)